Can't detect the twilio incoming call js sdk angular
I am using "@twilio/voice-sdk": "^2.11.2" and making twilio voice call in angular - already setup server url in twilMl app
Outgoing call is working fine but I am not able to get incoming call whenever i try to call on twilio number from my number call get disconnected on first ring
Can anyone help me out ?
I have added voicegrant incomingcall true
still not working

You should check the twilio error logs. There must be some error in webhooks.

@WaqasSaeed
In plain JS it's working fine
but while in angular
not getting console of device is ready even if token is correct
this.device.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Twilio.Device is ready for incoming calls');
});

You need to check the twilio error logs in Monitor -> errors in Twilio dashboard.
Also on the angular side you might not be handling the browser microphone permissions. If you can provide the angular code, I will be able to assist you better

Do you recieve ring on you frontend part or it just client hear ringing and call dissapear?
If 1st, check errors everywhere.
If 2nd, you probably failer with voice token, so twilio can't find a call reciever.
In call logs you should see 2 calls, 1st is from client number to your twilio number, 2nd from your twilio number to smth like client:<agent_identity>. And same identity should be used while generating voice token.
